# ios getusermedia from external usb-c microphone, the mic is recognized but the audio is still coming from the internal mic

Tags: progressive-web-apps, web-audio-api, getusermedia

I have an app that captures audio from a USB-C microphone connected to an iPhone 15 Pro Max for audio processing.

I initiate getUserMedia with the deviceId constraint and the exact behavior. When I check the deviceId on the created audio track, it matches the one I provided.

However, the issue is that the audio is still being picked up from the internal microphone of the iPhone.

Interestingly, on iPadOS, the app functions perfectly, successfully receiving input from the USB-C microphone.

Have any one a idea how i can solve this problem or is this a webkit bug?